# 2007 Nissan Quest RPM issues

Tags: engine, transmission, nissan

I have a 2007 Nissan Quest 3.5S. I notice that exactly at 20mph the rpm will be at a specific rpm then fluctuate to a higher rpm then come back down to normal rpm. Is this normal?

Comment: Does the vehicle have a CVT (**C**ontinuously **V**ariable **T**ransmission)?

Comment: I have no clue! but I will find out.

Comment: I don't think the CVT was available until 2010 or so.

Comment: 07 is not a CVT. How high of a fluctuation are you talking about?

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain, I will take a video of the car doing it...and post it.

Comment: Even a normal torque-converter auto can 'hunt' for gears like that. Some do it from the factory (Holden Commodores here in Aus had a habit of doing it with the four speed), others start doing it when the valves or bands start to wear out. Of course, some boxes start doing it when the fluid needs changing.

Comment: Is there any change in throttle position or speed when the rpm fluctuates? Is it accompanied by any lurching forward or back?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad - OP stopped responding.